# shrink div with padding or margin

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is the following.

I have a div with a fixed height, lets just say its `100px`.
What I want is a div within this 100px div with a height of `100%` but then `10px` shorter at the top and bottom.
So the result will be a wrapper div with a `100px` height and a div within this wrapper div which starts `10px` from the top and ends `10px` from the bottom (i.e. `height:80px`).
The problem is that I'm getting a div which has a total height of `120px`.

**Note: only html css solutions**
**Note2: the div inside the wrapper has a height of 100%**

CSS and HTML

```css
#t{
  height:100px;
  width:5px;
  background: blue;
}

#e{
  height:100%;
  width: 5px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}

#s{
  height:100%;
  width: 5px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="t">
  <div id="e">
    <div id="s">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JSfiddle I've been playing with
http://jsfiddle.net/MWUsM/2/

Comment: when you make the inner div `position:absolute; top:10px; bottom:10px;` instead of `height:100%` it should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the CSS `box-sizing` property `border-box`

The [box-model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) specifies the rendered width/height of the element as `specified width/height + padding + border`, and to subtract the padding and border properties from this sum, the [CSS3 specification adds `box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0)

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/MWUsM/5/)

Chris Coyier has a nice and detailed [article](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

For cross browser support, it's suggested you add the prefixes as follows:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: As an addition to your answer, I should also include `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` and `-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Nice point - included in the linked article, but I will all the same